# foreign key constraint in Lift's mapper

Tags: database, scala, lift, mapper

I created a table using *Mapper* in Scala.

```
class Stage extends Mapper[Stage]
{                   
  def getSingleton = Stage             
  object controlId extends MappedLongForeignKey (this,Control) {  
    override def dbNotNull_? = true  
    override def dbColumnName = "control_id"  
  }  
}
```

but my table does not create a constraint for the foreignKey key in database.

Comment: Please only use backticks for code format in comments or for short codefragments in a sentence. If you mark the text in the online editor, and hit the code-format button `{}`, it will pick the right code to layout your code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lift, [like Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#active-record-and-referential-integrity), does not create foreign key constraints by default.  If you want to enable them, you can do so via `MapperRules`.  Put this in your `Boot` somewhere before you do other database initialization stuff.

```
MapperRules.createForeignKeys_? = (_) => true
```

The var `createForeignKeys_?` is a function of type `ConnectionIdentifier => Boolean`.  I suppose this allows you to control foreign key creation per-connection, but most applications only have a single database connection.